# Help and Improvement Steward badge with less than 1000 edits

Tags: bug, edits, help-improvement

There are currently three people on this site with the steward badge for the Help & Improvement queue. Two of them have less than 1000 edits to their name for this year (resp. 950 and 940), and the queue has only started March this year.

It seems that either the edit count is incorrect or that there is a way to get a review counted in the H&I review queue, without doing an actual edit.
Is there a bug somehwere, or am I missing something (like edits to posts that are later closed are not counted)?

Comment: *Or* the posts they have edited have been deleted since.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That would make more sense as Close/On Hold would probably not make the edits not count. I must say I would find 5-6% of Improved posts (that were not triaged to be salvageable) being deleted quite a lot.

Comment: Well, looking at [edits like these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30088609/how-can-i-create-a-map-that-will-show-me-distance-and-navigation-between-two-loc) it doesn't surprise me in the least.

Comment: I found several deleted posts already, so yes, it is definitely deletions.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I dreaded for a moment you would have found one of my H&I edits as a bad example (and I am sure you could have, although I tend to skip the ones I think should have been marked as unsalvageable during triage). I was not aware that edit count would go down on post deletion, but it makes sense.

Comment: Well, now that you mention it.. how did [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29949581/revisions) salvage that question? That just needed to be closed, there is no problem description there whatsoever.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I upvoted the comment that asked for the question. I have had a similar discussion on U&L: do you improve something  (e.g. code layout problems, removing thanks, etc.) that also needs extension only the OP can provide or not. If you don't the rest of what the OP adds cannot benefit from an improved context which means even more editing to get the post in shape once complete. As always there is a gray area (and my hope of people being capable of learning, your criticism has been noted)

Comment: I'm not worried for your performance here; you genuinely want to help, I think. But when all the reviewer does is remove a comma and leave a gigantic mess behind, and then *stops reviewing the moment they get the badge*, I want to see if we can just revoke that badge. As a moderator, I don't have that power, but boy do I wish I had here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The discrepancy is due to deleted posts. Not all edits in the queue are equal, and not all posts are improved to the point they avoid deletion.

I'll have to see if we can do something about some of these reviewers; edits [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30088609/revisions) (look at the title) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29869614/revisions) only serve to polish the turd, nothing was improved there. These edits are not isolated incidents.

Comment: Going over my own H&I history (I don't have enough rep on [so] to see others' history) I found several reviews for which the posts are no longer available. So I am guilty of polishing some turds as well, the only excuse for that is that initially I thought that if we `[Skip]`-ped someone else would have to look at the turd ad infinitum as there is no explicit way to sent a question back to triage/onwards to closing, while in the H&R queue.

Comment: @Anthon: the queue now has a way to send posts back to Triage though, so use that when a post simply is not worth the attention.

Comment: @Anthon to complement Martijn comment, just click the "very low quality" link.

Comment: @Braiam Thanks for making that explicit, I had noticed, but it took me way over 1000 reviews to do so.

Comment: @Braiam: Oh, is that what it does? I would have expected one of the possible actions in the review queue to be marked up as a button. At the very least, it should be phrased as an action: "Flag this question as..." (Yup, let's do that), and not as a statement: "question is ..." (M-hm. Thanks for the information. <Skip>).